# How to display Views exposed filters fields as a table?

Tags: theming, views

I would like to display [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) "Exposed filters" fields as a regular **table**, where the first column would be the field label, and the second column would be the field options/select lists.

So for example from this:

[image: Views, exposed filters]

I would like to create this:

[image: Views, exposed filters as tables]

What is a possible solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier than I expected.

How-to steps:

1. Copy `views-exposed-form.tpl.php` (http://pastebin.com/V77CPxPG) from the [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module's `views/theme` directory to your own theme's `templates` directory (but some themes have their template files in their root directory! (or maybe even other directories like `theme` or sg. else)).
2. Copy ANOTHER instance of this file to the same directory, BUT now name it so that it also contains the particular view's machine name *after two dashes*:

   ```
   views-exposed-form--page_test_ct.tpl.php
   ```

   (like it's explained [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/44606/2368); you should give a unique machine name to your view!)
   So in my example, the machine name of the view is `page_test_ct`, like you can see it here:
   [image: Machine name of a view]
3. Modify `views-exposed-form--page_test_ct.tpl.php` like this:
   http://pastebin.com/1qfim7VX
4. Clear cache (theme registry).

---

## SCREENSHOTS

### BEFORE

[image: Views, exposed filters]

### AFTER

[image: Views, exposed filters as tables]

### AFTER; having some exposed operators and descriptions too

[image: Views, exposed filters as tables, plus some exposed operators and descriptions]